# WSL2 очень медленная загрузка сайта

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, wsl, wsl2, tailwind

Решил попробовать связку Nuxt'а и Laravel. Из-за Laravel решил установить все это себе на WSL. Запускаю локальный сервер на WSL, потом в браузере на винде перехожу на http://localhost:3000

Проблема заключается в том, что страница постоянно очень долго загружается, занимает это целых 25 секунд. С такой скоростью невозможно что-то разрабатывать, при малейшем изменении приходится ждать эти пол минуты. Непонятно, откуда такое время вообще берется, ведь это все на локалке делается.

[image: Загрузка сайта]

Облазил, кажется, уже весь гугл, нигде не могу найти решения. Можно ли вообще как-то ускорить эту загрузку?

Comment: Если билдить проект в продашкн, когда Tailwind вырезает неиспользуемые классы, то загрузка сайта ускоряется до 3 секунд. Но пока все это сбилдишь, пройдут те же 25 секунд

Comment: А WSL Вам для этого зачем? Напрямую всё прекрасно работает без задержек.

Comment: WSL сам по себе медленный, второй вроде уже чутка по шустрей но так же медленный. Если поставить докер то вообще о быстрой загрузке можно забыть=) Как вариант поставить рядом с системой какую-нибудь убунту и уже на ней что то делать

Comment: Поддерживаю. Связка Angular - Laravel почти мертвая загрузка. Разрабатывать с таким откликом невозможно...
Хотел пересесть на одну ОС. Задолбало переключаться. Линух только для laravel и нужен и именно на LAMP сервере. Проект не аля вордпресс. Angular, Flutter и остальное все под виндой прекрасно работает.
Под линухом графических редакторов нормальных нет, да и игруху не погоняешь.
Редакторы гимп и подобные рядом не курили с тем же фотошопом.
Вот тоже прошерстил все в поисках решения ускорения загрузки. Ответа не нашел...

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очень простой: у wsl медленный доступ к файлам вне файловой системы дистрибутива (то есть к /mnt/c,d,etc)

Переносите проект в его родную файловую систему, например в домашнюю папку - и все будет летать,  и под докером тоже